# How to change the volume of Tmediaplayer using a trackbar

Tags: delphi

I am new to Delphi 2010. I am using Tmediaplayer to play wma files in a loop. I want to change the volume of tmediaplayer. I googled ways to do so but they al seem difficult. Are there an easy ways to change the volume using a trackbar. Any suggestions on where to start ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure to include the **pertinent** parts of the code you are working on, and to indicate what you are having trouble with. If there is no code yet, you probably should not ask for help so soon, either.

Comment: Have you checked [`this article`](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/mediaplayer_vol.htm) ?

Comment: I've done exactly as that article but I'm not sure how to change the volume. I'm not sure when to call the procedure and how to call the procedure. I have MPSetVolume(MediaPlayer1 , Volume) ; It doesn't change the volume at any point.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how to use a track bar? Or do you want to know how to change playback volume?

Answer (score 4):

The VCL version of [`TMediaPlayer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer) does not provide any kind of volume control.  You would have to resort to direct MCI commands, such as the [`setaudio`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798662.aspx) command with the `(left|right) volume set to <factor>` flag.  The [`DeviceID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.DeviceID) property will tell you the device identifier that you can send commands to while the player is active.

The FMX version of [`TMediaPlayer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer) has a [`Volume`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer.Volume) property.  FireMonkey was introduced in XE2 though, so your D2010 does not have it.

Comment: The volume property is 0 to 1. So you can create a Trackbar (0 to 100), frequency 1.
Get trackbar.value/100. 
My test I heard only after 20 on Trackbar.